# OLS estimator of the slope

Tags: self-study, least-squares

For the model $y=\beta_0+u$

(i) How could we define the vertical distance from each point to the line that we are estimating ?

(ii) While minimizing, the derivative gives us result only related with $\beta_0$. In that kind of situations, how are we constructing Hessian matrix and is OLS estimator a result that we get after derivating our model  with respect to $\beta_0$ ?

(iii) How can we find $R^2$ ?

Comment: Thank you for adding the `[self-study]` tag. Please be sure to read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: I rolled back your question to the original because your edit *completely* changed it.  That makes nonsense of an upvoted answer that has already been offered to you.  If you have an entirely different question to ask, then it's ok to post it in a new thread.

Answer (score 4):

(i) The averaged squared vertical distance is the variance of $y$. The average absolute value is the mean absolute deviation

(ii) The least squares estimator of $\beta_0$ is the sample mean, $\overline{y}$, because the sample mean minimizes the function $ f(a) = \sum_i (y_i - a)^2 $

(iii) When you only have an intercept, none of the variance is explained, so $R^2 = 0$.

Comment: +1 Welcome to our site, Bernedette!  Thank you for a clear, succinct account of the answers to these questions.